# Anaconda install packages without connection

Tags: anaconda, package, installation, offline

I am trying to install packages for anaconda offline

I am behind a company network, i have no possibilities to use conda install or pip install, I also cant create and custom environment.

I have already downloaded plotly....tar.gz and others.

Is there any way to install packages completly offline?

conda install C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/python packages/plotly-4.5.0.tar.gz --offline

I already tried some manuals but i get errors like
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

Any help would be very nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! This is working behind a company proxy. Here with plotly as example

1. download package from https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch/

example: plotly-4.4.1-py_0.tar.bz2

2. safe package to C:/Temp/noarch/ folder (if it doesn't exist, create it)
3. in C:/Temp/noarch/ folder press shift + rightclick (open console) or use anaconda prompt and go to folder
4. type in

conda install plotly-4.4.1-py_0.tar.bz2 (other: conda install “package”)
example: C:\Temp\noarch>conda install plotly-4.4.1-py_0.tar.bz2